# だが、恋愛が終わりそうなときや終わったときは、それをより深く体験できるので、本を読むといい。

Tags: meaning

だが、恋愛が終わりそうなときや終わったときは、それをより深く体験できるので、本を読むといい。

Can someone explain what the より means in this sentence.
Does it mean compare?

My interpretation:
"But, when your love is about to be over or it is over, compared to that you can get a lot of experience so you should read the book."

The compare does not make sense here...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use better as an adjective?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47849/5010)